# How to provide an alternative for router.back() if the last item is not a Vue route?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am using `router.back()` with the vue-router. It works but the problem I can foresee happening is that a user might visit the page without a history by directly accessing. That or the user is coming from another domain.

Both scenarios are unwanted. In case of the previous route not being a proper Vue route, I want to provide an alternative.

So in that case instead of `router.back()`, I want to push something like `this.$router.push({ name: 'deal-list' });`

I know the routes can be check with `route.beforeEach` and I am already using it with my `router.js` file to maintain my query parameters like so:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!hasQueryParams(to) && hasQueryParams(from)) {
        next({ name: to.name, query: from.query });
    }

    next();
});
```

How would I check **within a component** though what the previous route is and adjust my link accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With vue router, you can set a `beforeRouteEnter` hook on the component directly to get a reference to the previous route.

The `this` variable does not reference the Vue instance in this hook. But, you can reference the Vue instance via the first param in the callback passed to the `next` function (`vm` in this example):

```
data() {
  return {
    previousRoute: null,
  }
},
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  next(vm => vm.previousRoute = from);
}
```

[Here's the documentation on navigational guards.](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Comment: Thanks, seem to have skipped that one in the documentation.

Comment: It does not work because you can not access `this` in `beforeRouteEnter` as described here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html The workaround is also described, you need to pass in a callback to `next()`.

Comment: Yep, you're right! I forgot about that. Updated my answer.

Comment: In order for this solution to work, the hook should be included in the view component rather than in the child components, so the route actually changes.